# using com.vaadin.data.util.filter.Or for filtering multiple values

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I need to filter a Grid column based on multiple values?  In other words, they choose 3 values from a dropdown, "Apple", "Orange", and "Meat".  Then the filter chooses all matching grid lines that have Apple OR Orange or Meat in them.  Would `com.vaadin.data.util.filter.Or` be good for this?  Any examples on how to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like something along these lines:

```
theContainerUsedByTheGrid.addContainerFilter(new Or(
  new Compare.Equal("propertyId", "Apple"),
  new Compare.Equal("propertyId", "Orange"),
  new Compare.Equal("propertyId", "Meat")));
```